# Discord.py - How to create invite to specific channel?

Tags: python, discord

I'm wishing to create invite links using discord.py to specific channels, rather than having to run a command in the channel I'd like the invite to send joiners to.

```
invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
```

This code will simply create an invite to the channel where the function was called. Is there any way to specify which channel they are created for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just specify a channel & call `create_invite()` on that one.

The code below makes an invite for a channel you tag (using `!invite #channel_name`), or the channel you call the command in in case you don't tag one.

```py
@commands.command()
async def invite(self, ctx, channel: discord.Channel = None):
    if channel is None:  # No channel tagged, create invite for current channel
        invitelink = await ctx.channel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
    else:
        invitelink = await channel.create_invite(max_uses=1,unique=True)
```

All you have to do is get the `discord.Channel` instance you want to create an invite for, and then call `create_invite()` on it, so you can do the same thing in case you always want to create an invite for the same channel (using it's `id`) for example.

Comment: Thanks, however I'm getting issues whereby 'Channel' isn't an attribute of discord (AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Channel')

Comment: Yes, you have to replace that with the type of channel you want to create an invite for, like a `TextChannel`, `GuildChannel`, ... take a look at the Docs for the different types: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=channel&check_keywords=yes&area=default

In your case it's probably `discord.abc.GuildChannel`

Answer (score 1):

The command creates an invite link for the channel it is called in.

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.create_invite

Comment: Is there an alternative that can be run in another channel to create an invite for either the server as a whole or a specified channel?